# What is the android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS permissions?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I can't seem to find it in the Manifest.permission page on the Android developer website. I see GET_TASKS but it's deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

As per @CommonsWare's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181078/4625829):

> `REAL_GET_TASKS` is a **`signature`-level permission**; it cannot be held by ordinary Android SDK apps.

Also a comment by @Gürol'Ca on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369859/4625829):

> `GET_TASKS` was a 'normal' permission which can be requested by 3rd party applications. However, `REAL_GET_TASKS`'s protection level is `signature` or system which cannot be requested by 3rd party applications.

When checking the official documents about [< permission > - android:protectionLevel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel):

> **"signature"**
>
> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the user's explicit approval.

Wasn't able to find a totally clear description, or a doc that defines it completely in detail. But I think basing from these, it seems that it is a permission with regards to [App Signing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#signing).

Cheers!

Comment: So does REAL_GET_TASKS replace the deprecated GET_TASKS, except it cannot be used by ordinary 3rd party Android apps?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. But, yeah. I think so. If you can see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27974754/4625829) of @Caqtus, it was mentioned that *this method is no longer available to third party applications: **the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak personal information to the caller***